# Vue-Router Mock With Vue-Test-Utils & Vitest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, mocking, vue-router, vitest

I'm trying to understand the logic of mocking the Vue-Router with Vitest.

For this, I tried to set up and mock my test environment on a very simple project. When I tried to proceed according to the [official documentation of Vue-Test-Utils](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html#using-a-mocked-router-with-composition-api), I always got an error. I don't know if it's because they use Jest.

Using [real vue-router](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html#using-a-real-router) solves my problem but I think it's better to mock vue-router.

Below, I first convey the source codes of the project, and then the error I received.

#### Home.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute()

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(route.query)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>Home</div>
</template>
```

#### Home.spec.ts

```
import {expect, it, vi} from "vitest";
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";

import Home from "../src/components/Home.vue"

it('Home Test', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Home)

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

#### vite.config.ts

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['./test/**/*.spec.ts'],
    exclude: ['node_modules', 'dist'],
    globals: true
  }
})
```

#### My error message is as follows:..

[image: Error Message 1]

[image: Error Message 2]

#### Methods I've Tried

I tried to mock vue-router like below

```
vi.mock('vue-router', () => ({
    useRoute: vi.fn(),
}))
```

or just

```
vi.mock('vue-router')
```

##### Here is my final Home.spec.ts file

```
import {expect, it, vi} from "vitest";
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";

import Home from "../src/components/Home.vue"

vi.mock('vue-router')

it('Home Test', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Home, {
        global: {
            stubs: ["router-link", "router-view"]
        }
    })

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I expected to see the `router-link` or `router-view` in `Home.vue`:

```javascript
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(route.query);
});
</script>

<template>
  <router-link to="home">Go to home</router-link>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

So, the `Home.spec.ts` should be something like this:

```javascript
import { expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../src/components/Home.vue';

describe('./path/to/Home.vue', () => {
  const useRouteSpy = vi.spyOn(VueRouter, 'useRoute');
  const getWrapper = () => mount(Home as any, {
    global: {
      stubs: {
        'router-link': { template: '<div/>' },
        'router-view': { template: '<div/>' },
      },
    },
  });

  it('the component should be mounted', () => {
    // ARRANGE
    const useRouteMock = useRouteSpy.mockImplementationOnce({ query: 'query' });
    // ACT
    const wrapper = getWrapper();
    // ASSERT
    expect(useRouteMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Some comments/words of advice:

- Use describes to boundary the test context
- Define a global function to mount the component, reuse instead of repeat
- Use `.spyOn()` and `.mockImplementation...()` to spy and mock
- Use some structured/straightforward way to write your test, like AAA [arrange, act, assert] or GWT [given, when, then]. I have been testing for a few years and still using it, it helps me to understand what I'm testing
- Use `.toHaveBeenCalled...()` to check if the mock worked as expected
- The stubs in the `mount()` function should be related with the components used in the template (so, if you're not using `<router-view>`, it should not be listed as a stub)

Hope that helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.. :) I especially liked the AAA system. I have implemented your codes but this time I am getting an error like this "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useRoute". In the line where we spy the VueRouter

Comment: I would say that something in your typescript config is messing with vitest. You can check how the `.spyOn()` syntax works in the [vitest](https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#cheat-sheet) or [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) docs

Comment: @Mocha_ Did you find a solution to the error "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useRoute"? I have the same issue

Comment: @Steve I'm sorry for late reply, after this error i started using "vue-router-mock" package. It works well for component or page tests, but I haven't used it for composable tests yet.

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone need to do the same thing, now you can easily mock the vue-router using [vue-router-mock](https://github.com/posva/vue-router-mock)

```
// for example
import { getRouter } from 'vue-router-mock'

test('should move to /dashboard', () => {
 const route = getRouter()
 wrapper.router.push('/dashboard')
 console.log(route.currentRoute.value.fullPath) // /dashboard
})
```